# nslookup gives timeout based on request - what gives?

Tags: domain-name-system, firewall, domain-controller, timeout, internal-dns

I have the following strange problem with the DNS lookups in our Windows domain (dns service runs on the domain controller):

from machine 'A':

- dns request for machines in the same network zone works
- dns request for adresses that are not "allowed" result in a timeout / no response

from machine 'B':

- both lookup requests work

Both machines use the same DNS server

This must mean that:

- the DNS server knows the correct addresses, and works correctly
- but: there is some other component (firewall?) in the network that intercepts some DNS requests, based on ckient machine AND request content, and decides to block this request by not returning a response.

This setup forces us to resort to using hostfiles for some connections, since the target machines are reachable.

What could be the reason to configure the network / firewall in such a 'broken' fashion, and what kind of firewall or other appliance has such 'functionallity'?

Comment: Define "not allowed" in the context of machine A? Is it specific domains, or every internet domain? The latter would suggest that it is performing lookups against a nameserver that has access to internal DNS data for your network, but not external DNS data.

Comment: @AndrewB "not allowed" as in we may not connect to that machine.